# Typeorm: How to make composite key in one table as foreign key in other table

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, composite-types

I'm using Typeorm JavaScript not Typescript for PostgreSQL in Nodejs application. I have a two tables:

- Resource
- Passenger
- In Resource Table I have `id and type` both are primary key and act
  as composite key.
- In Passenger Table I have `Driver_Id and Driver_Type`

I'm trying to make Resource Id and Type as foreign key to Driver_Id and Driver_Type. But when I do with Typeorm its create a table column like Driver_IDResourceID and DriverTypeResourceType.

I have tried almost everything mentioned in the Typeorm docs but nothing work for JavaScript version.

Any help will be appreciated.